# How can I encompass a region of a 2D Array with a square based on the elements in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

To provide a simple example, my problem is this:

I have a **2D array** of `1`s and `0`s. Most of the grid is `0`s, but there are some `1`s scattered in there. I want to create a square that encompasses all of the 1's without any unnecessary space by finding the indexes of *top-left* and *bottom-right* elements of such a square.

I hope this helps visualize what I'm trying to do:

```
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

   A   0 0 0 0 0_0_0_0_0 0
   B   0 0 0 0|0 0 1 0 0|0
   C   0 0 0 0|1 1 1 0 0|0
   D   0 0 0 0|0 0 0 1 1|0
   E   0 0 0 0|1 0 0 0 0|0
   F   0 0 0 0|0_1_0_0_0|0
   G   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   H   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So in this case, I would want to find the indexes of `B4` and `F8`. I am working in **Java** and would like a solution that does not use Collections.

Comment: Seems straightforward. What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the given array and track **minimum** and **maximum** indices (of both outer array and inner arrays) of the element with a value of `1`.

In Java in need to initialize a local variable before you can access it. Therefore, all `max` variables are initiated with a value of `-1` and `max` variables with a corresponding *array length* (*invalid indices*).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] grid = {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

    int minRow = grid.length;
    int minCol = grid[0].length;
    int maxRow = -1;
    int maxCol = -1;
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] == 0) continue; // skipping this element

            minRow = Math.min(row, minRow);
            minCol = Math.min(col, minCol);
            maxRow = Math.max(row, maxRow);
            maxCol = Math.max(col, maxCol);
        }
    }

    if (maxRow == -1) {
        System.out.println("The given array has no elements with value of 1");
    } else {
        System.out.println("minRow: " + minRow);
        System.out.println("minCol: " + minCol);
        System.out.println("maxRow: " + maxRow);
        System.out.println("maxCol: " + maxCol);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
minRow: 1
minCol: 4
maxRow: 5
maxCol: 8
```

***Sidenote***: from the perspective of object-oriented design, this functionality can be encapsulated in a *class*, let's say `MatrixStatistics`. That will allow you to store these data, and might be something like element count, or histogram of frequencies for each subarray inside an **object**. Which can be returned from a method (*as you know, it's not possible to return multiple values from the method*), or used as a field. As an example from the JDK of such a mutable object caring statistical data, you might take a look at [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) class.